# Admin creating new item in sitecore workflow

Tags: workflow, sitecore, sitecore-workflow

if workflow has been applied to one particular template . and admin creates new item using that template . in this case item is in draft state because initial state for workflow was draft .

so even if admin has created item it has to go throu workflow...

is there any way we can avoid this..we need to set initial state as draft for workflow for non-admin users.

please advice..thanks

Comment: workflow should be applied only for non-admin users and not for admin even if they create new item which has initial state as draft /

Comment: To clarify... if a non-admin creates the item then that item should be in a workflow. However, if an admin created the item then the item should not be in a workflow?

Answer (score 2):

It's a really bad practice to use Admin users for creating items, editing content, etc. and you should avoid it as much as possible. Use roles with permissions to edit everything instead.

Regarding the question - I'd suggest the following options:

- Create workflow *action* that checks whether the item was created by
  specific user, and moves it to the final state.
- Or (I prefer this
  one) create a workflow *command* "Quick Publish without review" and make it
  available to specific users only. But item will be still created
  in a draft state.

Answer (score 2):

We use a "skip approval" solution that allows admins the ability to use or bypass workflow by selecting a settings obj. We do it this way so that everyone can get the benefits of our blueprint template but not be required to use workflow. For our workflow people, theyll have to abide by the draft>aa(approve/reject)>approved while the bypass people can simply edit, click submit and their item is approved and published all in one click. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826467/how-to-programmatically-approve-a-content-item-in-sitecore/9929824#9929824) to check it out. thanks